# Unity D-PAD is not working on Android with a Joystick controller

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, joystick

I'm making a simple game test in Unity and trying to export a version for android and I want to use a joystick controller (a IPEGA 9076) conected by bluetooth with smartphone.

BUT, D-PAD doesn't work. Only the buttons.
And LT and RT (that was axis in Ipega controler) is not working too.

I've trying so many things ... someone with some possible solution?

```
   if (Input.GetAxis("DPad_X") > 0.5f)
        {
                //Debug.Log("Right");

        }
```

someone with some possible solution or a tip